# HTML5 Canvas & jQuery Simple Game Beginner Issue

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

everyone. I'm trying to make a simple game based on a random generated circle that is keyboard controllable. So far, so good, but the problem is that the circle leaves a trail when it moves. How can I prevent that from happening? Here is the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hfvEs
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function paint(){
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IQEtiKE/1/edit)**

Comment: `canvas.width = canvas.width` is a clever hack... however in some browsers it causes quite a loss of fps. Just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

You have the canvas size in the variables `w` and `h` already. Where you increment your dot position, you need to check if it is still in bounds, e.g.

```
if (d == "right" && d.x <= w + 10) d.x += 10;
if (d == "left" && d.x >= 10) d.x -= 10;
// ....
```